# Optimize recursive function that generates a sequence of chars

Tags: c#, recursion, optimization, caching, dynamic-programming

I have a function that needs to generate a sequence of num chars to test a security algorithm.

For instance, `patternLength` of `4` it would generate:

`["0000", "0001", "0002", ... , "9999"]`

and `3` would generate:

`["000", "001", ... "999"]`  and so on.

As we know, recursion can be pretty expensive and begins to slow to a crawl at higher lengths so I'm hoping to speed it up by using some caching or DP. Is this at all possible?

Current function with recursion:

```
private static List<char> PossibleCharacters = new List<char>()
{
    '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
};
public static List<string> SequenceGenerator(int patternLength)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    if (patternLength > 0)
    {
        List<string> prev = SequenceGenerator(patternLength - 1);
        foreach (string entry in prev)
        {
            foreach (char ch in PossibleCharacters)
            {
                result.Add(entry + ch);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add("");
    }
    return result;
}
```

My messy attempt. I'm building the list starting with length 1, then 2, and so on. It gets to `999` -> `1000` where it becomes wrong, it should be `999` -> `0000`. Of course, I'll need to clear the contents of the cache where the lengths aren't what I want.

```
// patternLength = 4
    string[] result = new string[10000];
    string[] cache = new string[10000];
    result.Append("");
    dp[0] = "0";
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;

    foreach (string entry in result)
    {
        foreach (char ch in PossibleCharacters)
        {
            cache[i] = entry + ch;
            i++;
        }
        result[j + 1] = j.ToString();
        j++;
    }
    return cache.toList();
```

Thanks all for your time.

Comment: Just use an `int` counter and convert it to string?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is inherently bounded by an O(10^n) minimum [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) (where n is the length of the tested string) and there is no way to bypass this limit without changing its' functionality. In other words, your code is likely **mostly** slow because you are doing a lot of work and not because you implemented the aforementioned work in a particularly inefficient way. Optimizing string generation is very unlikely to provide any significant improvement in run time. Utilizing multithreading is more likely to provide real-world performance improvements in your described scenario, so personally I would start from there. Additionally, if you only need to access each tested string once, it is preferable to to generate them one-by-one as they are used in order to reduce your program's space complexity. Currently you are storing every string for the entire duration of your program or function's execution, which is a potentially wasteful usage of memory if they are only needed once.